# can't use ctrl + click with preventDefault and return false

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm loading every pages in AJAX so I'm using return false on my links to load them in ajax.

Problem: if the guys want to open it in a new window he can't, ctrl+click activates the ajax as well, I haven't tried middle button because I don't have a mouse.

I then tried e.preventDefault and it still prevents the dude to open it in another tab.

Any idea how I could circumvent this?

(if you want to try: www.p1x3L.com)

Comment: Wow. Trying to use the web without a mouse must be a horrible experience all round...

Comment: I tried www.p1x3.com and middle-clicking the links opens a new tab.

Comment: @BenM Some people do it all the time.  Mobile devices? :)

Comment: True, but not to own a mouse?! ;)

Comment: I moved and only took my laptop with me, and I was scared that with a mouse I would only play video games... don't judge me :3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`e.preventDefault()` will prevent the link from being followed by the browser at all.

What I'd be tempted to do is just check the status of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (or <kbd>cmd</kbd> on a Mac) when the click occurs, and then handle the action.

You'll need to track the action of the keypresses. Consider the following example, which assigns a boolean value to `ctrlPressed`:

```
var ctrlPressed = false;

$(window).on('keydown', function(e) {  
    if (e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey)  ctrlPressed = true;
}).on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey)  ctrlPressed = false;
});
```

Now inside your `click` handler, you can just check the status of `ctrlPressed`:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {  
    if(ctrlPressed)
    {
        return true;
    }

    // Handle your AJAX here. No need for an else{} block 
    // since return true will already have executed.
});
```

Comment: shouldn't I declare ctrlPressed without the 'var' so I can use it globally thus in the on('click') function?

Comment: Don't clutter the `window` object ;)